# shell script works fully in terminal but not when run by php

Tags: php, shell

I have a shell script that uses unoconv and then pdftk. when i run the script through the command line it works exactly how i want it to. When i use `shell_exec($cmd)` in php with the same exact command it runs the script (i know because of the echo's in the script) but it looks like it does not use unoconv (and therefore cannot use pdftk). Any idea on how to troubleshoot this problem? here some code:

```
 if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    $fname = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $dir = "powerpoints/".$name."/";
    $ispdf = "1";

    $output = shell_exec('mkdir '.$dir);
    chmod($dir, 0777);
    echo $output;
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dir.$fname)){
        chmod($dir.$fname, 0777);
        $cmd = 'importppt.sh '.$name.' '.str_replace(".ppt", "", $fname);
        echo "\n".$cmd;
        $output = shell_exec($cmd);
        echo $output;
    }else{
        $message = "move_uploaded_file() Failed";
    }
```

and here is the shell script

```
 #!/bin/bash

 echo $1 ' is the argument:' $2 ' is the second   '
 STRING="/var/www/html/devclassroomproject/powerpoints/"
 echo $STRING$1/$2'.ppt   '

 unoconv $STRING$1/$2'.ppt'
 pdftk $STRING$1/$2'.pdf' burst output $STRING$1/$1'_%2d.pdf'
```

This is what is printed from echos:

```
importppt.sh pptest pptestpptest is the argument: pptest is the second 
/var/www/html/devclassroomproject/powerpoints/pptest/pptest.ppt
```

edit:
to decipher my debugging
the command: "importppt.sh pptest pptest"
importppt.sh being the shell script; pptest is the first and second argument

printed by the first echo in the shell script: "pptest is the argument: pptest is the second"

printed by the second echo in the script verifying the complete path of the pdf which does exist: "/var/www/html/devclassroomproject/powerpoints/pptest/pptest.ppt"

sorry for the confusion

Comment: I'm not a php coder, but it looks like if you add a line `echo name=$name , fname=$fname"` after the `chmod` line, you should see the source of your problem. good luck!

Comment: those values are passed into my shell script and then printed by the shell script so like i said, i know the command i am using is correct since the shell script is being run and it prints the arguments exactly the same as when i use the command line. thank you tho. im guessing php is either not recognizing unoconv or pdftk since i have downloaded them, or doesnt have permission to use them or something

Comment: well my point is your debugging text looks very suspect, i.e. `pptest pptestpptest is the argument: pptest is the second`. Did you pass in pptest as both the first and 2nd argument? Why are you getting `pptestpptest`. Possible that your `unoconv` is wonky, but I'd think that is much lower probablilty. You should get a mesg on std-err like `unknown cmd : unoconv`, OR `uoconv: usage : .....` Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Found out what was wrong. the answer is here
http://johnparsons.net/index.php/2013/08/05/how-to-keep-unoconv-apache-from-making-you-sad/

basically you have to set up a home directory for the user for apache2 as www-data and change the path to the shell in the passwd file

he doesnt mention it but the changes will not work unless you restart apache